# seeking or scrubbing a video stream in reverse

Tags: ios, ios7, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem

I've created a scrubber in my app that allows the user to scrub forwards/backwards through a video via [AVPlayer seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter].

The video that is being scrubbed is captured via an AVCaptureSession that uses AVCaptureMovieFileOutput. I've ffprobed the resulting .MOV and the results are as expected (e.g., on my iPhone 5s I'm recording at 120fps at approx 23000 kb/s with approx 1 keyframe per second).

Since there is only approximately 1 keyframe per second, it is difficult to scrubber backward through the video with any precision and without any lag (since it would have to go back to the closest keyframe and the compute the frame at my current scrubbing position).

So I'm wondering if there is a better strategy for smooth scrubbing? There are apps out there that do this really well (e.g., I've examined the Coach's Eye app and it records video precisely the same way I do and yet its scrubbing performance is quite good).

I'd be very appreciative of any suggestions.